# Can I use Speedlink Xeox SL-6556 gamepad with XBOX-360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

"Speedlink Xeox Pro Analog Gamepad USB" (SL-6556) has declared compatibility with PC and has a Xinput/Dinput switch. On Windows, it uses drivers for original XBOX-360 gamepad and is recognized as an original MS gamepad. It looks like a replacement for an original gamepad, though I did not find any official confirmation for that on [speedlink website](http://speedlink.com/?p=2&cat=4132&pid=28040&paus=1). They describe it just as a "gamepad for PC with USB port" with no references to MS XBOX.

Can I use this USB gamepad with the XBOX-360 console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as this model was found on new year sale I just bought it for testing. Now I can confirm, it really not supported by Xbox 360 :) Though on PC with Steam OS it successfully recognized as XBOX 360 gamepad and works ok with my steambox now.